# Why Isn't There a Tefila for Fertility?

Tags: tefilla, blessing, shemoneh-esrei, pregnancy-birth, children

Within Shmoneh Esrai we daven for everyone of these items below, except for childbirth.  Why?

> R' Yochanan said: Three keys the Holy One blessed be He has retained in His own hands and not entrusted to the hand of any messenger, namely, the Key of Rain, the Key of Childbirth, and the Key of the Revival of the Dead. ([Taanit 2a](https://www.sefaria.org/Taanit.2a.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Comment: Why would you expect prayers to specifically match up with those three things? What about the blessing of Refaeinu? Is there really a constant need of childbirth?

Comment: https://yeshtikva.org/awareness/fertility-prayer/

Comment: https://www.tehillim-center.co.il/sgula/30 and https://www.ynet.co.il/articles/0,7340,L-3847512,00.html

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok those aren't in shemoneh esrei

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok or the oldest: ויתפלל אברהם אל-האלהים וירא אלהים את-אבימלך ואת-אשתו ואמהתיו וילדו

Comment: @ShmuelGoldstein The prayer for fertility is one of the intentions in the blessing for the "produce" of the year. And if that is a question, bear in mind that the physical body has its source in the element of earth, like we mention in connection with funerals. (Dust to dust, etc.)

Comment: @Yaacov I'm not sure how much work it would be to source this, but I think your linkage of fertility to the מברח השנים section of the Amidah is the best possible answer to this question

Answer (score 2):

I would venture to say that the two out of three which we do pray for, rain and techias hameisim, are completely out of our ability to control. Having children, however, is something which humans are involved in.

Now of course this begs the question what about other brachos in Shmona Esrei which are also accomplished through human action, at least sometimes, such as Rifaeinu.

But I will point out the following regarding these three special items which Hashem Himself has the key for, and based upon this you rightfully argued should have all been included in Shmona Esrei. The two that were included weren't put into the sheilas tzorchav, requests for ones needs, section of Shmona Esrei, as was Rifaeinu. They were put into the section of shvach, praise, not bakashos or hodaah. Mentioning something a human can be involved is not shvach of Hashem. Therefore fertility was left out.

Of course if someone needs to be healed as far as fertility goes, they can always put in a personal supplication in its proper place.